# How does one configure TCP_NODELAY for libpq and postgres server?

Tags: c, postgresql, libpq, nagle

I am trying to ensure that TCP_NODELAY is set (Nagle disabled) for Postgres client and server. I can see that there is code in libpq to use the option when a TCP_NODELAY macro is defined. I've cloned the postgres repo, run:

```
./configure
make CPOT='-DTCP_NODELAY'
```

and tried to link against the resulting static library. That results in `undefined reference to symbol 'inet_net_ntop@@GLIBC_2.2.5'` adding `-lresolv` fixes that and then there are a number of other undefined reference issues. I haven't been able to find any official documntation on postgres and TCP_NODELAY.

Does libpq and postgres server use TCP_NODELAY by default? Or not?

Am I on the right track above? It seems like there should be an easier way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are on the right track, but the correct way would be

```
./configure CPPFLAGS=-DTCP_NODELAY
make
make install
```

No, PostgreSQL does not use `TCP_NODELAY` by default.